# Insert custom data to custom table on wordpress database

Tags: database

i need some help here

i wanna create some form for user to subscribe our article and store the data to database. i have tried to search it on google, but nothing worked when i tried that. i know that some plugin can do that but i dont know how to create the validation when user already subscribed and the form never show again.

how do i do to insert the data to my database?
hope you guys understand what the problem and any help will appreciate

thank you

here is my code

**the form**

```
                    <form action="<?php echo site_url() . '/insert-data.php'; ?>" method="POST" name="form-subscribe">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                <p>Name*</p>
                                <input type="text" name="subs_name" placeholder="Full Name*" required="">                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mt-3">
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                <p>Email*</p>
                                <input type="text" name="subs_email" placeholder="Email Address*" required="">                              
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mt-3">
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submitForm">Submit</button></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

**the action file aka insert-data.php**

```
<?php

    //setting up the form
    function insertuser() {

      $name   = $_POST['subs_name'];
      $email  = $_POST['subs_email'];  

      global $wpdb; 
      $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "subscriber";
      $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('subs_name' => $name, 'subs_email' => $email) );
      }

if( isset($_POST['submitForm']) ) insertuser();

?>
```

**Here is the table of wp_subscriber**
[image]

Comment: "how to create the validation when user already subscribed and the form never show again" - you can store the user's email in a cookie and check if the email already exists in your table, and if yes, then don't show the form. Your form is for both registered and unregistered users, right?

Comment: _"you can store the user's email in a cookie and check if the email already exists in your table, and if yes, then don't show the form."_ I know the validation is like this, but i dont know how to create the validation if i use 3rd party plugin (in here im using Hubspot). i wanna do that without plugin, and the problem i cant insert data to database, what's wrong with my code? _Your form is for both registered and unregistered users, right?_ yeah, it's right

Comment: You're trying to use WordPress functions in a non-WordPress file. Do some research on handling form submissions in WordPress. It's very well covered.

Comment: "the problem i cant insert data to database, what's wrong with my code" - you're already using the correct code (`$wpdb->insert()`) to do the database insert, but your `insert-data.php` file might not be loading WordPress - but even if WP is being loaded there, you should use a hook like `template_redirect` or `admin_post_xxx` to properly handle form submission in WordPress.

Comment: @JacobPeattie exactly, im trying to use Wordpress functions in a non-Wordpress file. Thank you for your answer, i will do some research for that

Comment: @SallyCJ i will research about hook like that form handle form submission, i will try more harder haha